# How to parse JSON value in python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get the active DB name, so I can then make a backup and store offline. When I run this below, I get an output of: `[('Stillman-SP', False), ('initial.bak', False), ('initial', True)]`

I only want to print the DB name, that has a value of True.

```
for item in status.json():
    tr = item ['dbName'], item ['active']
    table.append(tr)
```

status.json:

```json
[
    {
        "dbName": "Test-SP",
        "active": false,
        "lastModified": "2021/11/15 20:13:21"
    },
    {
        "dbName": "initial.bak",
        "active": false,
        "lastModified": "2021/11/16 15:42:35"
    },
    {
        "dbName": "initial",
        "active": true,
        "lastModified": "2021/11/17 20:42:10"
    }
]
```

So I am calling an API. I don't have a json file path.

```
  s.get(get_active, verify=False, headers ={'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, cookies=r.cookies)
```

`get_active` is the variable name that holds the API url.

Comment: Wrap that printing logic in a `if item['active']:`?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I will look at that, thanks.

Comment: Please post a snippet of `status.json`.

Comment: @BlairNangle I added a screen shot of it. I couldn't get it to save in the correct format.

Comment: @bkr88 saw the JSON, thanks! How are you getting the body of the API response?

Comment: Please don't add screenshots of text. Post the actual text [formatted as a code-block](/help/formatting) if necessary, since it allows people to easily copy it to test their solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Updated function

```py
def append_active_databases_to_table(filename: str):
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        return [db['dbName'] for db in json.load(json_file) if db['active']]

print(append_active_databases_to_table('./status.json'))
```

### Using map/filter (less efficient)

```py
def append_active_databases_to_table(filename: str):
    with open(filename) as json_file:
        return list(map(lambda db: db['dbName'], filter(lambda db: db['active'], json.load(json_file))))

print(append_active_databases_to_table('./status.json'))
```

### Test

```py
def test_append_active_databases_to_table():
    table = append_active_databases_to_table('./status.json')

    assert len(table) == 1
    assert table[0] == 'initial'
```

### `status.json`

```json
[
  {
    "dbName": "Stillman-SP",
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "dbName": "initial.bak",
    "active": false
  },
  {
    "dbName": "initial",
    "active": true
  }
]
```

Comment: @Jab thanks, I have updated `filename`'s type.

Comment: @Jab regarding your point on efficiency/succinctness, yep, totally agree! I have updated my code to reflect this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everyone I will check this out.